# How to see exact health/mana/stamina numbers

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is there a way to display your total and current amount of health/mana/stamina in Skyrim on screen while you're playing? Is there a console command I could run for example?

By default they are only seen as bars, and also only displayed when you're using them.

---

***Update:*** Found a command called `ToggleDebugText` which looked promising, but doesn't seem to do anything at all when I run it...

Answer (score 2):

I searched for a mod that displays the values too but didn't found one that just adds values to the existing bars.

However, there's a mod that features custom 'bars' with values: [**Attribute Icon Widget**](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/52197/?)

[image]
<sub>(source: [nexusmods.com](http://static-6.nexusmods.com/15/mods/110/images/52197-2-1395146223.jpg))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [nexusmods.com](http://static-2.nexusmods.com/15/mods/110/images/52197-1-1396033733.png))</sub>

Ps: Didn't tested the mod but seems promising.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Skill menu during combat and your stats will be displayed on the bottom. Here's an example [image]

Comment: Yeah... that's not an option during combat, sorry :P Nor very practical out of combat for that matter...

Comment: @Svish it would be pretty easy to reach over and pause, on console the pause buttons aren't far and if you are fast you can do it on PC too

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion of checking your skill screen is decent. It does take a bit of time to go from battle to that screen and back, but it's totally doable. Another benefit is if you are in a dire emergency and have a level up available. When you pick a stat to increase(which you are forced to do in that case), all your stats get immediately topped off. It's like an emergency full heal.

That said, using the console is faster (in the sense you can immediately turn it on and off to pause and unpause the game) and technically more accurate, as is can show a couple decimal places versus just integers. Type prid 14 and hit enter. Then follow with the getav command(s) for the stat(s) you want to know. Those are getav health, getav stamina and getav magicka. I'm pretty sure 14 is the default code for your character. You need to hit enter after every command.

Don't know if you know, but the ?/ key is a shortcut to the skill screen. Mind you that getav commands will only show the current state of your stats, not what they would be when full. Maybe this doesn't really answer your question since you want to see current and total stats simultaneously.